# Where is Application delegate registered in our Cocoa/Cocoa-touch app

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

Every app has an application delegate.

Where in the code that we specify/register that "SomeClass" (subclass of UIApplicationDelegate) is a delegate of my application ?

Comment: It is not a subclass of `UIApplicationDelegate`. It is a class that conforms to the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol

Comment: Plus, to nitpick, it is not the class that is a delegate, but an _instance_ of the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Storyboarding, this is done in main.m with the line:

```
UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

If the fourth argument to `UIApplicationMain()` is not `nil`, the function will create an instance of the specified class and assign it as the `UIApplication` object's delegate.

If you don't use Storyboarding, the connection is made in `MainWindow.xib` where the application delegate object is created and connected as the delegate of the File's Owner (which is the `UIApplication` instance, which in turn is created by the `UIApplicationMain()` function).

Comment: It's done with `UIApplicationMain` regardless of whether you use storyboards. I'm not sure when the change happened, but as of Xcode 4.2.1, none of the Cocoa Touch templates use a main nib.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I find the application delegate for my apps...

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

The class name for the app delegate is just the name of your app followed by "AppDelegate". You will see that class in the list of files for your project, but it is created automatically. Just look for the file "MyAppDelegate.m".

This class is assigned delegate responsibilities in the MainWinodw.xib of "windowing" apps. If you are not using a windowing app, you will probably find the assignment in a call to `UIApplicationMain` in your "main.m" file.

Comment: Where do we specify that `MyAppDelegate` is our application's main delegate

Comment: Sorry, I've clarified that above. But I see Ole has just said the same thing below while i was editing! In any case, hope you found the info you needed.